Me sale el JPA controller vacío, sin los métodos
Tengo una clase java que la quiero mapear. Tengo el @Entity y todo. Paso el código más abajo. Cuando creo el JPA controller me sale sin los métodos. Vamos vacío y me da el siguiente error:

Esto de abajo es parte del código de la clase a mapear:
@Entity
public class Alumno implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    @Basic
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaNac;


Gracias de antemano a los que tengan a bien ayudarme. Saludos.

Lo he podido solucionar. Tuve que cambiar el pom.xml y el persistence.xml
Han quedado así:
Las primeras imágenes son del pom.xml y la tercera del persistence.xml.




Hola Luis, me alegra que lo hayas solucionado, te sugiero que edites tu auto-respuesta,  agregues el código como texto, así evitarás los votos negativos.
